# mongoose unable to connect authorized db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I installed the mongodb 3.4.1 on the ubuntu 16.04 and hosted them on digital ocean.

My local mongo client  was mongochef 4.5.2

At first, I didn’t  set up the authorization for my app,  it’s hacked, and was asked for bitcoin as ransom. 
So I tried to set up the authorization. However, encountered a wired problem, once set the `authorization: enable` in **the /etc/mongo.conf** .  It’s unable to connect the db remotely and locally with the `mongoose` , and got the error **auth failed**. But it could be connected with the terminal and the mongoChef.

here is my connection with mongoose

`global.db=mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:admin123@ip:27017/nodedb');`

and i also tried

`var  options = {     user : "admin",     pass : “admin123",     auth : {authMechanism: 'MONGODB-CR'} }
global.db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://@ip:27017/test',options);`

and also changed the ip  with localhost and 127.0.0.1 locally, failed the same.

Just in case the localhost and 127.0.0.1 didn’t recognised. Also set the configuration in the /etc/hosts with:

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 computename

update~:

there are two users in my admin DB. One is root user. And another one is admin with password admin123 which authenticated DB **nodedb**

really exhausted by this problem, has any one encounter this problem???

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the authSource (the database against which it is authenticated). So, if the `authSource` is `admin` it should be specified in the connection options.

```
options = {
    "auth": {
        "authSource": "admin"
    },
    "user": "apiuser",
    "pass": "admin123"
};

// If host=localhost, port=27017 and database name=nodedb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodedb', options);
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu. I tried your solution but the problem the same.  Please see additional update above related to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is done at a database level. In your connection string db is nodedb, but your password is stored in admin database. You can connect to nodedb either by adding a user to this db or by defining db for auth with --authenticationDatabase admin. You can read more here.
For more info, please check manual http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/

Comment: thanks newbie.  I already added a user to the nodedb that's admin: admin123.  Though this user is authenticated to the nodedb. But it actually stored in the admin DB. Are all the users in mongodb required to store in admin??

Answer (score 0):

Access your nodedb from terminal(mongosh) then show users. Then check your user roles. Add role for readWrite to user for the nodedb database if it does not exist.

```
    use nodedb
    show users
    db.grantRolesToUser('admin',[{role:'readWrite', db:'nodedb'}])
```